# Rolling product remains gap filling

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Product remains at some date are calculating by product operations(incomes and expenses) like balance from money transactions.

I have a materialized view with rolling product operations where every operation projected to corresponding product remain at the moment when the operation had been performed via window functions (`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`).

[image]

But if I want to get product remains for date and no product operations were performed at this day, then I can't receive remains.

How can I fill the gaps for days with zero product operations? 
How to do it efficiently, with minimal cost?
Is there another way to get product remains efficiently?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: In addition to ways showed in answer, it also could be done by filling in the gaps on client side.   If you care about amount of passed data between client and Postgres, this might have more sense.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can fill in the data using `generate_series()`:

```
select p.product_id, coalesce(t.created_at, gs.dte),
       coalesce(volume, 0),
       coalesce(remaining_volume, 0)
from (select product_id, min(created_at)::min_ca, max(created_at) as max_ca
      from t
      group by product_id
     ) p cross join lateral
     generate_series(min_ca::date, max_ca::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) left join
     t
     on t.product_id = p.product_id and
        t.created_at::date = gs.dte;
```